# SparkStreaming with Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I have kafka version 3.2.3, I constantly get an error when I try to connect kafka with SparkStreaming that the files I use are not compatible, does anyone know which version of sparkStreaming can be used with Kafka 3.2.3

I am trying to connect SparkStreaming and Kafka on OpenShift